# Win 10 zip upload reorders blocks of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Our system has been used to upload millions of files over several years. The clients use the following code to send an authentication token and zip file to our WEB API on Windows Server 2008 R2. On our Windows 7 devices, the system works great. As we are attempting to move to Windows 10 devices, we have suddenly encountered an issue where the received file has blocks of data in a different order than the source file. The problem only occurs about half of the time, which makes it very difficult to track down.

client code (.NET 4.5)

```
private static void UploadFile(string srcFile, string username, string password)
{
    if (File.Exists(srcFile))
    {
        ConnectionUtilities connUtil = new ConnectionUtilities();
        string authToken = connUtil.GetAuthToken(username, password);
        using (HttpContent authContent = new StringContent(authToken))
        {
            using (HttpContent fileStreamContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(srcFile)))
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(srcFile);
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                using (MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
                    formData.Add(authContent, "auth");
                    formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "data", fi.Name);
                    var response = client.PostAsync(ConfigItems.hostName + "UploadData", formData).Result;
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        File.Delete(srcFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WEB API code (.NET 4.5.2)

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostUploadData()
{
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        MultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider =
                MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/app_data"));
        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
        string auth = streamProvider.FormData["auth"];
        if (auth != null)
        {
            auth = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(auth);
        }
        if (Util.IsValidUsernameAndPassword(auth))
        {
            string username = Util.GetUsername(auth);
            foreach (var file in streamProvider.FileData)
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataRoot"]);
                di = di.CreateSubdirectory(username);
                string contentFileName = file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                di = di.CreateSubdirectory("storage");
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file.LocalFileName);
                string destFileName = Path.Combine(di.FullName, contentFileName);
                File.Move(fi.FullName, destFileName);
            }
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
}
```

The problem initially manifests as a zipped file that can't open in Windows. Only by doing a hexadecimal compare did we determine that the file was all there, just not in the same order as the original.

Any thoughts on what might be causing the blocks of data to be reordered?

P.S. I know the HttpClient is not being used as effectively as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some long and tedious testing (Yay, scientific method) we determined that our web content filter software was causing the issue.